# How to disable request signing in boto3 API or cognito authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

How do you disable request signing, and therefore the requirement that you have valid AWS API credentials setup locally?

I'm trying to write a script that an anonymous user can use to authenticate to an AWS Cognito User Pool, and to simplify the process, I don't want to require that they first setup their own AWS account and get API credentials. I just want them to submit their username and password and be issued the authentication token.

The Python code to do this is fairly simple:

```
import boto3
provider_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='us-east-1')
resp = provider_client.initiate_auth(AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH', AuthParameters={ 'USERNAME':'<myusername>' , 'PASSWORD':'<mypassword>' }, ClientId='<myclientid>')
```

However, by default, boto3 requires you to have AWS credentials setup, and if you don't, this code fails with the error:

```
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

This makes no sense to me. You shouldn't need AWS credentials just to authenticate a user login.

And sure enough, after studying the traceback, if I go into the code at `botocore/signers.py", line 160, in sign` I see:

```
if signature_version != botocore.UNSIGNED:
    kwargs = {
        'signing_name': signing_name,
        'region_name': region_name,
        'signature_version': signature_version
    }
    if expires_in is not None:
        kwargs['expires'] = expires_in
    if not explicit_region_name and request.context.get(
            'signing', {}).get('region'):
        kwargs['region_name'] = request.context['signing']['region']
    try:
        auth = self.get_auth_instance(**kwargs)
    except UnknownSignatureVersionError as e:
        if signing_type != 'standard':
            raise UnsupportedSignatureVersionError(
                signature_version=signature_version)
        else:
            raise e

    auth.add_auth(request)
```

So presumably, there's some setting that supports issuing unsigned requests. If I manually comment out this if statement simulating the case where `signature_version = botocore.UNSIGNED`, then my code works perfectly and I'm issued the authentication token. But obviously I don't want to have to hack the boto3 codebase just to authenticate.

I'm having trouble following all the function calls, and I'm not sure how to configure boto3 so that it uses `signature_version = botocore.UNSIGNED`. How do I force it to use unsigned requests for this specific call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following with boto3:

```
import boto3
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.config import Config
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
```

The equivalent with the awscli is to add `--no-sign-request`.